# Prove that $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$ $(\exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N})$ such that $(x_k)_n = (x_{k_0})_n (\forall k \geq k_0) $ in this metric space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $X = \{a = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} | (\forall n \in \mathbb{N}) a_n\in\{0,1\}\}$ be space with metric $d:X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$d(x,y) = 0$$ when $x = y$ and in other case $$d(x,y) = \frac{1}{2^i}$$ where $i = \min\{n\in \mathbb{N} | x_n \ne y_n\}$.

Let $(x_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ be convergent sequence in $(X,d)$. Prove that $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})$ $(\exists k_0 \in \mathbb{N})$ such that $(x_k)_n = (x_{k_0})_n (\forall k \geq k_0).$

So, if $x_k$ is convergent (its limit is something, I'll call it $a$) that means that $d(x_n, a)$ has to be arbitrarily small. Somehow I feel that if it's true, what is asked to prove must be fulfilled, but I am not sure how to write that down nicely. Can someone please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists $k_0$ such that $d(x_k,a) <\frac  1{2^{n}}$ for $k \geq k_0$. Now $d(x_k,a)=\frac 1  {2^{i(k)}}$ where $i(k)=\min \{j: (x_k)_j \neq a_j\}$. For $i <i(k)$ we have $(x_k)_i=a_i$. We also have $(x_{k_0})_i=a_i$ if $i <i(k_0)$. Hence, $(x_{k})_i=(x_{k_0})_i$ if $i <\min \{i(k),i(k_0)\}$. Now note that $d(x_k,a)=\frac 1  {2^{i(k)}}<\frac 1 {2^{n}}$ which implies $i(k) >n$. We also have $i(k_0) >n$. Hence $i \leq n$ implies  $i <\min \{i(k),i(k_0)\}$ and so $(x_{k})_i=(x_{k_0})_i$. In particular $(x_{k})_i=(x_{k_0})_i$ holds for $i=n$.